# Div with background as a subset of body background

Tags: html, css

Don't know how to properly word this, but tried to implement this codepen:

https://codepen.io/danielkvist/pen/LYNVyPL

The div background is a continuation of the actual body background.
When taking it apart and implementing my own, the div doesn't continue, instead becoming it's own background.

Implementation [here](https://cover-hack.glitch.me), what's missing to mimic the codepen?

Main point of interest appears to be:

```
.overlay {
    background-color: var(--lightblue);
    background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dbhnlktrv/image/upload/v1599997626/background_oeuhe7.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    left: -100%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    width: 200%;
}
```

Comment: Your implementation requires a login, can you share it on codepen, jsfiddle or include it in your question?

Comment: The implementation is the login itself?

Comment: That makes sense! I thought you were going to use the same bg image so thought I had to login to see it... went right over my head!

Comment: `background-color: transparent;` it's the box shadow that is giving the impression of displacement.

Comment: @pilchard That was it, just an illusion I guess. Good catch! is there a term for this besides displacement?

Comment: @pilchard There is certainly a bg image on the overlay container, so while using `transparent` might achieve the same results, it's doesn't appear to be the same implementation as the codepen

Comment: Sorry, was said tongue in cheek, but simplicity has its charms. I saw there was an image and tested the transparent solution before commenting though.

Comment: @pilchard hey it works, i looked at the codepen for a little, but the implementation is verbose and complex - I would go with `transparent` as well :)